# Why this Ruby + Qt code not working?

Tags: ruby, qt

I have the following test code:

```
require 'Qt'
app = Qt::Application.new( ARGV )
wnd = Qt::Widget.new
layout = Qt::VBoxLayout.new( wnd )
splitter = Qt::Splitter.new( layout )
```

That fails in last line with strange error:

```
'initialize': unresolved constructor call Qt::Splitter (ArgumentError)
```

I have checked the `Qt::Splitter` API via `rbqtapi`, it has constructor that takes one `Qt::Widget` argument. What's wrong with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout` is of type `VBoxLayout`, which is *no* base class of `QWidget` and thus cannot be used where an argument of type `QWidget` is expected.  Guessing based on my experience with Qt in C++ and Python, I'd say you have to use:

```
splitter = Qt::Splitter.new(wnd)
layout.addWidget(splitter)
```

Comment: Hmm.. Seems it's a friday :). Thanks a lot!